# How to delete multiple contacts for the user in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I could delete multiple phone calls through `Mass Updates`. I can delete single `contact`,`lead`,`customer`...etc in `UI` and `RESTlet` code.

I want to delete multiple `contacts,leads, customers, prospects, partners and vendors` in `UI` and also using `RESTlet` code.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a simple, custom mass update script that can be deployed to delete any record type using the Mass Update functionality.  At the most basic, it would look like this:

```
function deleteRecord(recordType, recordId) {
    nlapiDeleteRecord(recordType, recordId);
}
```

Create a new Mass Update script and deploy the script to Contact records.

Then you can start a new mass update, select Custom Updates and you should see your custom mass update listed there.  Then it works just like any other mass update.  You build your query to select the records you want to delete, then click the Preview button, then click the Perform Update button.

When I deploy this script, I make sure that it's only available to the Administrator role and I usually leave it in Testing which makes it available only to me.  It means I really need to be sure of what I'm doing before I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Prabhu,

In javacript, either within a RESTlet or even client side, I'd build an array of items to delete, then iterating through with a for loop, call `nlapiDeleteRecord`.

If your lists contains items with children, it'll throw an error, so wrap the 
`nlapiDeleteRecord` with a `try/catch` block, so you can keep processing your list.

For those cases where records have children, you may need to build a special case or function to delete them too.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the reply. Is there any possibility to delete contacts in UI?

Comment: If you can open the contact for editing, there should be a delete option in the "Actions" dropdown list to the right of the main buttons

Comment: I can do for single . I meant multiple contacts in UI. Sorry for making misunderstand

Comment: Not that I'm aware. Id use a saved search to create a list of things I want to delete. Then use that list and call `nlapiDeleteRecord`. Otherwise you could manually make a list of `internal IDs` you want to delete, save it into a JS file (as an array), then write a function to take that list and delete everything