# Mass delete all inventory items in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am new to Netsuite , 
Is there anyway to delete all inventory items  at once in Netsuite?
Is there any way to convert all inventory items to lot inventory items?

Thank you
Madhura

Answer (score 3):

You can delete nearly any type of record in bulk with a [custom mass update script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750236/how-to-delete-multiple-contacts-for-the-user-in-netsuite/35752051#35752051) which essentially looks like this:

```
function deleteRecord(recordType, recordId) {
    nlapiDeleteRecord(recordType, recordId);
}
```

Just deploy this script to whichever record types you want to delete and select it from the Mass Update screen (it will be listed under custom). You still have the same restrictions in place that you would have deleting that record from the UI.  If the inventory item has been used or has dependencies, then it cannot be deleted.

As for converting, you cannot convert inventory items to non-inventory items.  You can however, convert non-inventory items to inventory items.

Comment: I am new to Netsuite , Do you recommend any online Netsuite tutorials . I would like to learn the scripting.

Comment: The NetSuite help file has great documentation for scripting.  The API is well documented and has some starter examples for each type of script.